# setting a style attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a simple little dropdown bar that gets triggered on a button click. I have it in working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sir_charles804/bC4WD/13/ , but it will not run on the site. Any ideas why? On the site there are angularjs jQuery and bootstrap so I'm not sure one of those is getting in the way. The code on the site is

**HTML**

```
<div id="notificationBar">
    Latest Major News Update
    <button class="pull-right" style="position:relative;" id="hideButton" >notification   </button>
</div>
<button class="pull-right notificationButton" id="showbutton">notification </button>
```

**JS** (defined in the body right now for testing)

```
var showNotifications = function () {
    document.getElementById("notificationBar").style.marginTop = "-8px";
};
var hideNotifications = function () {
    document.getElementById("notificationBar").style.marginTop = "-40px";
};

var showButton = document.getElementById('showButton');
var hideButton = document.getElementById('hideButton');

showButton.onclick = showNotifications;
hideButton.onclick = hideNotifications;
```

**CSS** (in an external sheet)

```
#notificationBar {
  display: block;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color:black;
  height: 30px;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 4;
  padding:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  margin:0px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-40px;
  -webkit-transition:margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
  transition:margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow:1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
```

see anything wrong?

**Edit:**

If I manually change the css to reflect the transition then it appears, so it seems that my issue is accessing the attribute in javascript. Do you know what would cause me to not be able to access/change the `style.marginTop` property? or why changing that property would not lead to the margin being changed?

Comment: Might be worth posting a link to the site if you can.

Comment: It might be a js conflict or something. Check your browser console for possible messages

Comment: could you provide a link to the site where it doesn't work? would help me a lot to debug it

Comment: Do you have any errors on your site? You can find them e.g. in the developer console of Google Chrome.

Comment: Don't play with margins. Just set `display` to `block` or `none` if you want to show or hide your notification bar.

Comment: What is position value for parent element notificationBar?

Comment: Site is not live, so I can't link you to it. It is not producing errors. The reason I am not using the display attribute is because I want it to slide down like the fiddle does.

Comment: Maybe using jQuery slide-in effect for that?

Comment: My only issue is correctly changing the margin attribute. If I go into the CSS and manually change the `margin-top`, the bar displays.

Comment: Are you running your javascript after your button is available in the DOM, by using something like jQuery's `ready()`?

Comment: No its just in a `<script>` tag right below the buttons and I've tried putting it above and it doesn't change. Do you think that would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by putting that function into `window.onload = function() {};`

My problem was that it was trying to assign the `onclick' property of undefined.